# Manipulate spool command output in Bash Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, scripting, sqlplus

I am running an sql query from a bash script using spool and getting the below output.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin/sqlplus -s esg/esg << EOF
spool /tmp/test

< SOME SELECT QUERY >

spool off;
EOF
exit;
```

I am getting output as below:

```
cat /tmp/test


TABLESPACE_NAME          USED_PCT
------------------------------ ----------
TEMP_TBS1                  23
SYSAUX                     4
GTEMP                      3
SYSTEM                     3
UNDOTBS2                   0
UNDOTBS1                   0
TEMP                       0
USERS                      0
DATA_TBS1                  23
INDEX_TBS1                 11

10 rows selected.
```

I want to get rid of everything except the values i.e., I do not want header,"--","10 rows selected" and ofcourse blank lines. This would look like below

```
TEMP_TBS1                  23
SYSAUX                     4
GTEMP                      3
SYSTEM                     3
UNDOTBS2                   0
UNDOTBS1                   0
TEMP                       0
USERS                      0
DATA_TBS1                  23
INDEX_TBS1                 11
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a shell question, but in your heredoc, before the spool, add some SQL*Plus formatting commands; e.g.:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin/sqlplus -s esg/esg << EOF
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
spool /tmp/test
...
```

Setting [pagesize to zero](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-6DB11E90-9B72-4100-8A8A-BF9BD345D0EB) "suppress[es] all headings, page breaks, titles, the initial blank line, and other formatting information".

Setting [feedback off](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-2C90B73B-A7E0-4357-9382-5EBAF53BF528) removes all feedback like '10 rows selected'.

There is a summary of the `set` commands [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html). There is also a section on [formatting SQL*Plus reports](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/formatting-SQL-Plus-reports.html).

Comment: I think `set heading off` also required as per OP

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 - setting pageszie to zero turns off headings too.

Comment: @AlexPoole I was exactly for it. Thank you very much!! It worked.

Comment: @AlexPoole It is working for Oracle 12.2 but it not working Oracle 11.2. Can you help me  what parameters I should set for 11.2 version?

Comment: @AmanSingh - those settings haven't changed (since at least Oracle 7 I think), so nothing needs to change. It shouldn't matter but do you mean using the 12.2 instant client to connect to an 11.2 database, or using the 11.2 instant client (or some other client) to connect to a different DB version? And what doesn't work?

Comment: Ok I got the issue. sqlplus with "-s" option is not working and hangs in my other solaris system with oracle version 11.2. I am able connect to my database as `sqlplus / as sysdba` but when I am using Silent option `sqlplus -s / as sysdba` commands hangs and no output is displayed.

Comment: I've never seen `-s` cause a hang, unless the credentials were wrong so it sits at the login prompt - but I think that wouldn't be an issue with a heredoc anyway. You can add the `-l` flag in case that could be an issue.

Comment: That's very strange issue from script -s option is working fine but from CLI it isn't. I have asked my DBA to troubleshoot . Anyway Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Alex's solution - but if you do want all that output in your spool log, and just want to strip out the relevant bits for something else, try `sed`, which will allow layers conditions.

```
$: sed -n '/^---/,/^$/{ /^[A-Z]/p }' test
TEMP_TBS1                  23
SYSAUX                     4
GTEMP                      3
SYSTEM                     3
UNDOTBS2                   0
UNDOTBS1                   0
TEMP                       0
USERS                      0
DATA_TBS1                  23
INDEX_TBS1                 11
```

Breaking that down:

`sed -n` says don't print anything unless explicitly ordered.
`/^---/,/^$/` says do the following command on lines in this range only.
`{ ... }` says apply the contents of the braces when the previous conditions apply, so since the previous condition was a range select, this allows multiple commands to be executed collectively on each line in the range.
`/^[A-Z]/p` says print only if the first character is a capital letter.

Collectively, all this says "for lines between dashes and a blank line, print if and only if they begin with a capital letter". Everything else will be ignored.